# Nested import between ipynb files doesn't import properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using `import_ipynb` module to import one jupyter notebook inside another.

`txt2csv.ipynb` has the following import statements

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import import_ipynb
import config as cfg
```

I am using another file to import `txt2csv.ipynb` which has following import statements

`data_processing.ipynb`

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import datetime
import import_ipynb
import txt2csv
```

My issue is that when I try to use a statement like

```
data_in = glob.glob(os.path.join(cfg.data_dir, "*.csv"))
```

inside `data_processing.ipynb` it throws the error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-683b1d3df82f> in <module>
----> 1 data_in = glob.glob(os.path.join(cfg.data_dir, "*.csv"))

NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Are nested imports not possible in python, will I have to explicitly write `import os` again in `data_processing.ipynb` file?

Comment: _Are nested imports not possible in python, will I have to explicitly write import os again in data_processing.ipynb file?_ I'm not sure if there is any functionality specific to Notebooks, but no, you should import it yourself.

Comment: @AMC I see, I wrote a system few months back where I did the nested imports I am talking about. I checked the source code for it this morning to see how I did earlier. Turns out I was mistaken and that it is not possible to do that (afaik).